# restore backup mysqldump php

Tags: php, mysql

i can't seem to restore my database backup in php. this is my code

```
<?php
        $host = 'localhost';
        $user = 'root';
        $pass = ' ';
        $dbname = 'itravel';
        date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kuala_Lumpur'); 
        $date = date('Y_m_d');
        if(isset($_POST['backup']))
        {
            $backup = "c:/xampp/mysql/bin/mysqldump --opt -h $host -u $user $dbname > itravel_backup_$date.sql";
            system($backup);
        }

        if(isset($_POST['restore']))
        {
            $restore = "c:/xampp/mysql/bin/mysqldump --opt -h $host -u $user $dbname < itravel_backup_$date.sql";
            system($restore);
        }
        ?>
```

backup was successful but the restore is a failure. help me guys!

---

updated the code with

```
<?php
        $host = 'localhost';
        $user = 'root';
        $pass = ' ';
        $dbname = 'itravel';
        //date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kuala_Lumpur'); 
        //$date = date('Y_m_d');
        $backup_name = 'itravel_backup.sql';
        if(isset($_POST['backup']))
        {
            $backup = "c:/xampp/mysql/bin/mysqldump --opt -h $host -u $user $dbname > $backup_name";
            system($backup);
        }

        if(isset($_POST['restore']))
        {
            //$restore = "c:/xampp/mysql/bin/mysqldump --opt -h $host -u $user $dbname < itravel_backup_$date.sql";
            //system($restore);
            $restore = "c:/xampp/mysql/bin/mysql --opt -h $host -u $user $dbname < $backup_name";
            system($restore);
        }
        ?>
```

but still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `mysql` binary to restore, not `mysqldump`.

Comment: im having a hard time researching that mysql binary. can you please help me?

Comment: @AkaM: Unix follows a "one tool for one job" principle, and `mysqldump` is used to dump databases or tables. `mysql` is the binary that is used to actually execute mysql statements (what a dump effectively is).

Comment: @arukiri123: it should be in the same directory as the `mysqldump` binary. It takes the same arguments as `mysqldump`, so you should be able to just replace `mysqldump` by `mysql` in your command line string.

Comment: something like this: $restore = "c:/xampp/mysql/bin/mysql --opt -h $host -u $user $dbname < $backup_name";

Comment: changed mysql to mysqli but still can't restore