# php fails to restore backup sql

Tags: php, mysql

i'm creating a restore database script in php but its not working. this is the code so far

```
<form action = '' method = 'POST'>
            <h2>Restore</h2>
            <table>
            <tr><td><input type=file name="file"></td></tr>
            <tr><td><input type = 'submit' name = "restore" value="restore"></tr></td>
            </table>
        </form>

        <?php
        $host = 'localhost';
        $user = 'root';
        $pass = ' ';
        $dbname = 'itravel';
        //date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kuala_Lumpur'); 
        //$currentdate = date('YmdGis');
        $restore_name = $_POST['file'];
        $custompath = $_POST['path'];

        if(isset($_POST['restore']))
        {
                $restore = "c:/xampp/mysql/bin/mysql -h $host -u $user $dbname < $backup_name";
                system($restore);

        }
        ?>
```

nothing happening after clicking the restore button. please help

Comment: What are you getting with `get_mime_type()`?  You need to debug this somewhat yourself.  There isn't enough to go off of here.

Comment: Any chance you could look at the log and see what `c:/xampp/mysql/bin/mysql -h $host -u $user $dbname < $backup_name` returns (or the return value of the `system()` call)?

Comment: Yet another "debug my code for me" question... but of course it's PHP blamed for this

Comment: See if this helps you. http://stackoverflow.com/q/14799987/827224

Comment: @YourCommonSense i'm just asking for help. i tried a lot of things. i know this script was working before. it just went like this.

Answer (score 2):

```
$restore = "c:/xampp/mysql/bin/mysql -h $host -u $user $dbname < $backup_name";
                                                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

nowhere do you define `$backup_name`. Shouldn't it be `$restore_name`?

Uploads also do not appear in `$_POST`. They show up via `$_FILES`.

You should also NEVER assuming an upload succeeded. Especially for a mysql dump file. It is possible that the upload was truncated, yet you blindly feed the file back into MySQL, which could leave you with a partially/totally trashed database.

**ALWAYS** check for upload errors:

```
if ($_FILES['files']['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
    die("Upload failed with error " . $_FILES['files']['error']);
}

$restore_name = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name']; // temp file PHP stores upload in
```